# Regular Expression Help - Lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to validate some input text (this is part of a larger regex)  and basically I have a list of values, Replaced with arbitrary characters in this example and I want to match that they have the correct convention..

IE I want to match AAA001 but not AAA00 and match ZZ00.

I want the AAA and ZZ's to be returned as the same group, IE group 1, but the digits excluded..

here's where I'm up to:

```
^((AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3})|(ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YdaulGpdbyK738T6)

Where am I going wrong with the concept of lookahead's? I've tried reading but to no avail.

Thanks

Edit:

so this is an example of the full 'obfuscated' regex..

```
^(?:OOO)(ABC|DEF)(RR|AA|DD|EE)((?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3})|(?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SZkxpm1wslHhcHgc)

so in my latest example above.. I would want group 3 to return AAA|BBB|CCC but not contain the digits.. if possible then group 4 could return the sequence number but not important, they can be discarded..

David

Comment: It will work if you move the `$` inside the look-aheads. Since the look-ahead doesn't consume character, you are asserting end of string after AAA and ZZ

Comment: Can you give some samples of input you want to match? And others you don't want to match?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `\b((?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}\b)|(?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}\b))`? See https://regex101.com/r/cP1oX7/3.

Comment: Your last debuggex picture is kind of beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting as I can forget to do it later :))

If you want to place `AAA` and `ZZ` into 1 group, and are planning to use the regex in larget strings, you can use `\b` instead of `^`/`$`, and put all the alternatives into non-capturing groups, and add one capturing group around them all:

```
\b((?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}\b)|(?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}\b))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP1oX7/4)

**EDIT:** Since the question is updated, I think this can be considered:

```
^
(?:OOO)                     # "OOO"
(ABC|DEF)                   # "ABC" or "DEF"
(RR|AA|DD|EE)               # "RR" or "AA" or "DD" ior :"EE)
(
  (?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}\b)  # "AAA" or "BBB" or "CCC" if followed by 3 digits
  |                         # or
  (?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}\b)     # "ZZ" or "XX" or "YY" if followed by 2 digits
)
.*                          # anything up to the end
$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP1oX7/5). Perhaps, instead of `.*` we can just consume the found digits using `\d{2,3}`. Please check what suits you best.

Answer (score 2):

```
^((AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}$)|(ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}$))
```

Update: Sorry -- (I should have read the comments) this is in fact the suggestion of @nhahtdh

Update2: with the full regexp (again we are moving `$` into the look-ahead expressions)

```
^(?:OOO)(ABC|DEF)(RR|AA|DD|EE)((?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}$)|(?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}$))
```

Replacing `^` and `$` by word-boundary (`\b`) as suggested by @stribizhev is obviously a good idea.

Comment: Ok so the above works spot on, however I could have sworn that I tried the $ within the look ahead. Not sure I understand the word boundaries bit though. Much appreciated though :)

Comment: David, remember `a(?=b)$`  **always fails**: it means `a` followed by a `b` that y will not consume (zero length string), followed by end-of-string. It is impossible:  `a` followed by b (=`ab`) and `a` is followed by `(zero length string)$` (=`a$`)

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, the following works fine and will also take a look at word boundaries and try and understand that option too :)

working solution shown here for clarity:

```
^(000|111|222)(ABC|DEF)(RR|AA|DD|EE)((?:AAA|BBC|CCC)(?=\d{3}$)|(?:ZZ|XX|YY)(?=\d{2}$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bht8J1S00aJcWt8f)